# port 3000 for express, port 8081 for react native, how to make get request

Tags: android, ios, express, react-native, native-base

I am using React Native for an avatar builder that I want to deploy to iOS and Android. I am using Express for my server, which uses localhost:3000, react native uses localhost:8081.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Container, List, ListItem, Header, Title, Content, Thumbnail } from 'native-base';
import { Action } from 'react-native-router-flux';

export default class Class extends Component {
  componentWillMount(){
    axios.get('https://localhost:3000')
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
}

render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header><Title>Choose Race</Title></Header>
        <Content> contents here <Content>);}}
```

I get the following error in the react native debugger

```
Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:15)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (event-target.js:172)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (XMLHttpRequest.js:542)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (XMLHttpRequest.js:378)
    at XMLHttpRequest.js:482
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (EventEmitter.js:181)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (MessageQueue.js:236)
    at MessageQueue.js:108
    at guard (MessageQueue.js:46)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the android emulator, `localhost` refers to the android system. You use `10.0.2.2` to refer to it. E.g. `http://10.0.2.2:3000` ([How to connect to my http://localhost web server from Android Emulator in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806220/how-to-connect-to-my-http-localhost-web-server-from-android-emulator-in-eclips))

In the iOS emulator though, `localhost` does refer to the host machine: [How do I access the host machine itself from the iPhone simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077888/how-do-i-access-the-host-machine-itself-from-the-iphone-simulator)

You will probably have to do some platform-specific logic while you test locally, example:

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

const host = Platform.select({
    ios: 'localhost',
    android: '10.0.2.2',
});

// ...
    axios.get(`http://${host}:3000/`)
    // ...
```