# Web service call from visual studio xamarin in ios

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

We are developing an iOS shopping cart application in c# and Visual Studio 2017 for Xamarin. We are using rest web services, Here I could not call web services. when I call web service  I am getting null response with an error[ConnectFailure (Connection refused)]. My question is How to get a value from localhost URL like [http://localhost:56207/api/Users/Raju/Password@123]. When I enter this URL in the browser I am getting true or false depending upon user and password validation.I request you to help me to resolve this issue.I paste the code in below:

```
 public class RestInterfaceImp : IRestLogin
    {

    HttpClient client;
    private const string WebServiceUrl = "http://localhost:56207/api/Users/Raju/Password@123";


    public async Task<List<User>> RefreshDataAsync()
    {

        try
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();

            var resp = await httpClient.GetAsync(WebServiceUrl);


            if (resp.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var respStr = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

               var listaAtletas = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(respStr);

            }

        }
        catch (HttpRequestException e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.InnerException.Message);

        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: You can get result in browser(from computer I believe) because your computer browser can reach that localhost URL, but how iOS app from either simulator or a real device is supposed to know and reach a URL in your computer?

Comment: According to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6077929/5941852):
The iOS Simulator uses the host machine network so you should be able to just use localhost or your machines IP address, whichever IP your web service is listening on.

Comment: That said, will you get any result when entering that URL in iOS simulator(say Safari)?

Comment: I've never had success connecting to an api by just using localhost:<port> but others are saying it's possible.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's working now

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we need to expose a local api to a simulator like you are doing, we use ngrok:

https://github.com/inconshreveable/ngrok

For some reason their website is down right now so it's possible they are no longer a thing but here is the url:

https://ngrok.com/